# How do I add a new location where Ubuntu 20.04 will look for desktop launchers?

Tags: 20.04

Just like adding a $PATH to the /etc/environment file, I want to add a new path that application menus will search in. Currently, I know the global desktop launchers are located in /usr/share/applications. Is it possible to add a global path like /go/apps/launchers?

Comment: There is an existing location for users: `~/.local/share/applications`. It's unclear why you seem to want to add *another* global location. Why won't the existing global location work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Desktop Menu Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-0.91.html)

> $XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications/
> This directory contains a .desktop file
> for each possible menu item. Each directory in the $XDG_DATA_DIRS
> search path should be used (i.e. desktop entries are collected from
> all of them, not just the first one that exists). When two desktop
> entries have the same name, the one appearing earlier in the path is
> used.
>
> **The <DefaultAppDirs> element in a menu file indicates that this
> default list of desktop entry locations should be scanned at that
> point. If a menu file does not contain <DefaultAppDirs>, then these
> locations are not scanned.**

So find a menu file and edit as per the description:

> <DefaultAppDirs>
> This element may only appear below <Menu>. The
> element has no content. The element should be treated as if it were a
> list of <AppDir> elements containing the default app dir locations
> (datadir/applications/ etc.). When expanding <DefaultAppDirs> to a
> list of <AppDir>, the default locations that are earlier in the search
> path go later in the <Menu> so that they have priority.

[File locations](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/ar01s02.html)
You should be able to find or create a menu file in `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS/menus/` if $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS is set.

For me, this leads to `/etc/xdg/menus/gnome-applications.menu/`

---

If you really must add a global path for your use case, you'll have to add a path to $XDG_DATA_DIRS. You'll probably see something like `/etc/profile.d/xdg_dirs_desktop_session.sh`, but `/etc/environment` is probably the best place to [set the path system-wide](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-permanently-set-path-in-linux/).

Something like:
XDG_DATA_DIRS="/go/apps/launcher:$XDG_DATA_DIRS"

Comment: Adding XDG_DATA_DIRS="/go/apps/launcher:$XDG_DATA_DIRS" to /etc/environment caused kde5 to crash. I added it to the end of /etc/profile and everything worked as expected. Thank you.

Comment: I also created a folder in launcher directory called "applications" and placed my desktop files in there. Doing that allowed the files to show up in my start menu.

Comment: I didn't expect that. I read that /etc/profile sources from /etc/profile.d as well https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Computer_Science/Operating_Systems/Linux_-_The_Penguin_Marches_On_(McClanahan)/02%3A_User_Group_Administration/5.03%3A_System_Wide_User_Profiles/5.03.2_System_Wide_User_Profiles%3A_The_etc-profile.d_Directory#:~:text=/etc/profile.-,d,customization%20scripts%20of%20their%20own.

Comment: You created the directory `/go/apps/launcher/applications` after adding `/go/apps/launcher` to XDG_DATA_DIRS? Was that a preference or did you have to do that before it would find the .desktop files?